# Reading cell values of Aspect map using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, csv, aspect

I have generated an aspect map from a DEM using ArcGIS and I want to create a CSV file containing the cell values using the arcpy library. I have done reading raster maps using the arcpy library previously with "RasterToNumPyArray" function. But aspect map cannot be read like that.

How to read the cell values in aspect map and generate a CSV file?

Comment: Why cant it be read as a numpy Array?

Comment: RasterToNumPyArray ist the way to go, since aspect was calculated as a Raster.

Comment: What do you want your csv file to contain? (1) The raster itself, i.e. columns and rows representing x and y coordinates? (2) a cell count per aspect ratio class?